# After JEP 220 changes does tools.jar equivalent ship pre-installed with JRE?

Tags: java, java-9, tools.jar

[Migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1) seems to state that after [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) both JDK and JRE install in `lib` directory

> dynamically linked libraries and the **complete** internal
>   implementation of the JDK.

Since it says "complete" does this mean, for example, `tools.jar` which previously did not ship with JRE, now indeed ships on JRE as part of `libjvm`?.

Analysing Ubuntu packages

- [openjdk-11-jre-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/openjdk-11-jre-headless/filelist)
- [openjdk-11-jdk-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/openjdk-11-jdk-headless/filelist)

it seems JDK version does not install anything extra under `lib/` although it does install bunch of modules under `jmods/`. AFAIU, `.jmods` are relevant if one ships app with modular image, however they are not strictly necessary for building an application?

I understand similar question has been asked many times in pre-JDK9 world, however after JEP 220 introduced significant changes, what extra APIs are provided by JDK installation that are not provided by just JRE installation?

Comment: The `.jmod` file are packaged modules, used by the `jlink` tool, nothing else. Everything is modules now, no need for tools.jar since JDK 9. The classes that used to be in tools.jar are now in their respective modules (jdk.compiler, jdk.javadoc, ...). What is your issue?

Comment: @AlanBateman Seemingly, I am able to call Java compiler API with just JRE installation, whilst pre-9 I had to have full JDK because, AFAIU, compiler API was in tools.jar which only shipped with full JDK. Thus, I am wondering if now just JRE has everything one needs including what was previously in tools.jar?

Comment: Does `java --list-modules` list `jdk.compiler`? If so then you are using a run-time image that has the java compiler.

Comment: @AlanBateman Indeed, there exists `java.compiler` and `jdk.compiler`. I guess JRE now does ship with complete APIs, or it could be just how Ubuntu decided to package it. Do you mind posting your comments as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: If `jdk.compiler` is listed then it means the `javac` compiler is in the run-time image. What does `java -version` and `which java` say? Asking because it sounds like an installation issue or that your PATH isn't set correctly.

Comment: @AlanBateman `javac` CLI tool is not installed anywhere on the system according to `sudo / -name javac`. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu with only [openjdk-11-jre-headless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/openjdk-11-jre-headless/filelist). `which java` gives `/usr/bin/java`, whilst `java -version` gives `11.0.6`.

Comment: I can't tell what is going on there, maybe they are stripping binaries from the run-time image. I suggest a bug report to point out that the java compiler is in the jdk.compiler module, it's crazy for a run-time image to claim that it has this module but not have the java launcher.